# Microsoft Visual Studio Is Waiting For An Internal Operation To Complete

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday, I sent my computer to sleep but kept VisualStudio open, together with my solution. Which is the most likely cause for the following problem:

When I first tried to browse my still-open solution this morning, I got "Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete." I gave VS like 10 minutes, but nothing changed. The processor load is 5%, disk load close to non-existent, memory consumption normal.

So I went for taskmgr, took good aim and shot VisualStudio down.

When I now started VisualStudio again and tried to open my solution, it would stall again during opening, with the same error message. So I killed VS again, then rebooted my PC. But, you guess it, when opening my solution after that, it stalled again.

I googled for the error message, but the problems/solutions I found were mostly wrt debugging. I am quite sure that I didn't send a running debugging session to sleep yesterday. Also, the rdpclip process isn't running. Furthermore it only happens with this solution - I can create new solutions and projects and work with other projects.

I already replaced the sln file with a backup, but it didn't help. I did not find "new" files (changed today or yesterday) in the solution directory, apart from some cs files and the compiled DLLs.

So now I am at the end of my knowledge. Is there any leftover "lockfile" somewhere in the Programs directory, which I should delete to be able to work again?

EDIT: I just stopped the last attempt to let it run through. The "operation", whatever that is, was not finished after **more than 2 hours**.